# Storing URI as String into SharedPreferences causes Formatter exception

Tags: android

I have a strange behaviour when I try to store the URI of a directory as a String in SharedPreferences:

First I start an intent to get a directory

```kotlin
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER)
```

Then in `onActivityResult` I try to store the result as a string (data is the Intent)

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
// checks left out for simplicity
val targetDir = data.data.toString()

val storagePreference : ListPreference? = findPreference(resources.getString(R.string.settings_storage))
storagePreference?.summary = "External: $targetDir"
}
```

When I then select a folder (for example Downloads/Rec) the intent returns `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FRec` as Uri and when I convert it to String and try to set the summary as shown above, the App crashes:

```
   java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'F'
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2782)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2812)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2625)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2558)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2505)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2870)
```

The reason are the Url encoded parts in the string, because if I replace '%2F' by '/' the storing works.

The `storagePreference?.summary = "External: $targetDir"` is the failing line. Why can't the summary string contain "%F2" or similar strings?

Comment: You are not using format(). I see no call.

Comment: "when I convert it to String and try to store it it causes the Formatter to fail" -- could you show your code for doing this? You should be using `Uri.parse()`.

Comment: There is nothing to decode.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong part included - I adjusted the code above. The error happens when I set the summary of the ListPreference. The ListPreference is calling the formatter internally, I don't call it explicitly.

Comment: Using `storagePreference?.summary = "External: ${URLDecoder.decode(targetDir, "UTF-8")}"` works, but why do I have to decode this in the summary string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `ListPreference` source code (see below) the summary property is anticipating a format string, in fact you can see how `getSummary()` is using `String.format`, which will choke on the encoded characters in your URI.

It seems the suggestion to decode the Uri string is a reasonable solution.

```
/**
     * Returns the summary of this ListPreference. If the summary
     * has a {@linkplain java.lang.String#format String formatting}
     * marker in it (i.e. "%s" or "%1$s"), then the current entry
     * value will be substituted in its place.
     *
     * @return the summary with appropriate string substitution
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        final CharSequence entry = getEntry();
        if (mSummary == null) {
            return super.getSummary();
        } else {
            return String.format(mSummary, entry == null ? "" : entry);
        }
    }

/**
     * Sets the summary for this Preference with a CharSequence.
     * If the summary has a
     * {@linkplain java.lang.String#format String formatting}
     * marker in it (i.e. "%s" or "%1$s"), then the current entry
     * value will be substituted in its place when it's retrieved.
     *
     * @param summary The summary for the preference.
     */
    @Override
    public void setSummary(CharSequence summary) {
        super.setSummary(summary);
        if (summary == null && mSummary != null) {
            mSummary = null;
        } else if (summary != null && !summary.equals(mSummary)) {
            mSummary = summary.toString();
        }
    }
```

This wasn't obvious reading the developer docs for `ListPreference` though...